# Site breaks when trying to disable cache on dev site

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, fatal-error, memory-leak

My dev site is an exact clone of my live site (barring the `local.xml` file to make the dev site talk to the cloned database), hosted under a separate domain name on the same web server.

When I try to disable the cache on the dev site, I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 65552 bytes) in
>   /home/devsite/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 1615

This is fairly unhelpful in determining what the root cause of this issue is. Nothing seems to appear in any log files, so I am fairly stumped as to what is causing this problem - and only on the development site?

I have flushed cache storage and sessions via SSH, and also cleared out all log tables in the dev copy of the database.

Can anyone shed any light on what is causing this issue?

Comment: Try doubling the max memory size, that will help you figure if this is a gigantic task or some kind of infinite loop.  At the top of your index.php add `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`. You currently have it at a gig which should be loads, but this may help narrow down whats going on.

Comment: That actually got the issue resolved. It turns out that in the last update for the theme my site uses, there is something that must trawl through the entire product catalog to do some updates, and I am assuming that was tripping it out. Returning everything back to normal (memory_limit) after the site has successfully loaded up, and everything works as expected once again! Thanks for the suggestion, I was skeptical, but everything is worth a try!! :-)